# Comparison between the expected values of the inverse of the CDF of binomial-distributed random variables

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, inequalities, convex-optimization

Let us denote with $F(x;j,\mu)$ the cdf of a Binomial distributed random variable with $j$ trial with success probability $\mu$ considered in $x$, and let $f(x;j,\mu)$ be the pmf. Defining $0\leq \gamma \leq 1$ is it possible to derive an ordering between $E[\frac{1}{F(x;j+1,\mu)}]$ and $E[\frac{1}{F(\gamma x;\gamma j +1,\mu)}]$? i.e.:
$$
\sum_{s=0}^{j}\frac{f(s;j,\mu)}{F(s;j+1,\mu)} \leq or \ge \sum_{s=0}^{j}\frac{f(s;j,\mu)}{F(\gamma s;\gamma j+1,\mu)} 
$$
This result could be useful to prove the effectiveness of discounted policies in reinforcement learning, making possible to derive upper bounds for their performance as the $\frac{1}{F}$ is ubiquitous in bandits and reinforcement learning literature. I tried to attack this problem with this paper's results on stochastic ordering (see [this paper by Braouezec and Cagnol](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.01412)) due to the well known relation between beta and binomial distributions, but i feel there must be something better because the knowledge of the crossing point introduced in the aforementioned paper results critical. Thank you in advance for your kind attention.

Comment: Must $\gamma j$ be an integer? If not, how is $F(\gamma s;\gamma j+1,\mu)$ defined?

Comment: @IosifPinelis we shall take the nearer higher integer (sometimes in bandits literature they are quite sketchy about it, I think for example in the seminal work on Thompson Sampling by Agarwal and Goyal), but I agree with you, to be well defined must be integer and the higher nearer one

Comment: Another way to deal with non-integer values of $\gamma j$ is to use the expression of the binomial cdf in terms of the incomplete beta function. This way, you get analyticity wrt the non-integer "number of trials". Which way (one or the other) do you prefer?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I tried this approach that you're suggesting (with the paper linked) but seems to me that the only thing we can get with known results with beta distribution is that there's effectively a point in which the inverse of the cdf will cross and the one with the least variance will dominate, but the crossing point is not generally known so it appears impossible to draw conclusion for the mean, so I returned to the "classical" approach where the problem to be well defined must take the higher nearer integer of $\gamma j$, but if it is known some relation in the "beta realm" is fine too

Comment: (i) "will cross" what? (ii) What do you mean by "conclusion for the mean"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis (i)it does exist an unique crossing point $x_c \in (0,1)$ such that $Pr(Beta(\gamma \alpha,\gamma \beta)\ge x) \leq Pr(Beta(\alpha, \beta)\ge x) $ for $x\ge x_c$ but I couldn't derive anything on the expected value(ii)I need to compare the expected value of $\frac{1}{Pr(Beta(\gamma \alpha,\gamma \beta)\ge x)}$ and $\frac{1}{Pr(Beta( \alpha, \beta)\ge x)}$ (fixed x) evaluated with respect of $\alpha$ and  $\beta$,  $\alpha=wins$ and $\beta=fails$ of the same binomial process (mean $\mu > x$), but I obtained nothing with stochastic ordering of beta distributed rvs

Comment: @IosifPinelis with slight abuse of notation I've written as $Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ a Beta-distributed rv with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152309/discussion-between-marco-max-fiandri-and-iosif-pinelis).

Comment: Sorry, I don't engage in such chats. However, I have another question: Do you want your inequality to hold for all $\gamma,j,\mu$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis sorry I didn't want to bother you, mathoverflow proposed this way of communicate after some messages and I thought it was common, sorry again. It would be desirable to find for every $j \ge 1$ and $1>\mu>0$ and $\gamma \leq 1 $ but further restraints on $\gamma$ wouldn't be a problem. Thanks again for your patience and attention

Comment: Or even a lower bound on j (i.e. valid for j>someting) wouldn't be a problem, my guess (coherently with the experimebtal result of the empirical literature on discounted RL) is that those with higher variance (characterized by $\gamma \alpha$ and $\gamma \beta$) will have a lower expected value